# Packet delimiter in netcat source file

Tags: netcat, multicast

Is there a delimiter or some way of telling netcat how many bytes to send per packet from a file?  Invoking netcat multiple times in a script is not acceptable as I need to send them out as fast as possible.

I have captured UDP packets with binary data into a file using mnc (multicast netcat) and attempt to play them back as follows:

# start program sending multicast packets to 230.250.5.1 12340>

# start mnc to capture packets:

```
 $mnc -l -i eth1 -p 12340 230.250.5.1 >capturefile
```

...
   # playback packets using netcat, sending to 230.250.5.1 12345

```
 $netcat -c -w 1 -u -s 10.20.30.40 230.250.5.1 12345 <capturefile
```

capturefile appears to have the packets I want to send.

When I play back with  netcat  the packets are concatenated.  UDP packet size is 208 during packet capture and wireshark shows 250 as packet size, I assume that includes ethernet bytes.  On replay, wireshark shows packet size of 1016.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be possible for you, but if you use `socat` instead of `netcat` you can set a fixed block size quite easily with `-b`:

```
socat -b 208 - udp4:230.250.5.1:12345 <capturefile
```

If you have variable length data you might look at using `tcpdump` and `tcpreplay` and the `pcap` file format.